# Removing titles in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, genesis

I have this website http://www.vocaloid.de/Wordpress/

and I try to remove the titles below the thumbnail on the home directory and on the category sites using this command:

```
if(is_home() || is_front_page() || is_category()) {
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_entry_header_markup_open', 5 );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_do_post_title' );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_post_info', 12 );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_entry_header_markup_close', 15 );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_footer', 'genesis_post_meta' );}
```

But somehow they do not get removed.. How can I fix this?

I checked the code and it is working fine without the if structure

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty way would be to css it out using:

```
h2.entry-title {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: But then the title would not show up in the full article view

Comment: Actually I inspected the code before posting. The full article view is using an h1.entry-tile. So it shouldn't be affected.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to `display:none;` because that's bad for SEO. I recommend installing a Wordpress plugin called "Hide Page and Post Titles" to show/hide page titles.